# Post-apocalyptic zombie manhwa or manhua involving a main character who is back from the future after being betrayed by his blonde wife

Tags: story-identification, manga, post-apocalyptic, zombie

Please help guys, I'm searching for a manhwa or manhua. I can't remember the name, it's been a few years.

The main character (MC) is back from the future after being betrayed by his blonde wife and killed in the process. The setup is a post apocalyptic zombie world and humans gain super powers. The zombies are super powerful and fast, depending on their abilities.

The MC has two sons, one with black hair who was always mistreated in the family (I can't remember if it's because he was the son of the first wife, who died, or some other reason), and the blond son, who was well-treated; he is the son of the blonde wife. The black-haired son has a super powerful ability, I don't remember which ability.

The last thing I remember is their group meeting a military group while traveling to another city. While stopping in a gas station, they had to fight some powerful foes with stealth ability (zombies or humans) in the building near the gas station.

If you can recognize it please provide me with the name. I can give some more details about the story if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this ***[Rebirth](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/rebirth-69michi)***...? It's a manhwa which is available to read at [Webtoon](https://www.webtoons.com/en/sf/rebirth/list?title_no=1412&page=10).

> What would you do if you are given a second chance to turn back time and relive your past? Would you do what you did back then for fear of the butterfly effect? Or would you take a different course of action and let the future speaks for itself?

The main character is a man named Noah Collins. He has a blonde wife named Parish and two sons, Abel and Neo. Abel has blond hair and is Noah's biological son. Neo has black hair, but is the product of an affair between Parish and Noah's asshole brother, Ian. Noah discovered this several years after Neo was born, and as a result, his relationship with Neo is rather strained.

The story begins with Noah regressing to the past, after having experienced six years of a zombie apocalypse, during which he was ultimately betrayed by Parish and Abel. The zombie apocalypse -- referred to as 'Armageddon' within the story itself -- began with a solar eclipse that caused many people to fall asleep then turn into zombies, while some of the human survivors gained superhuman powers. Noah has the power to manipulate his own blood and use it as a weapon, while Neo has an earring that allows him to store things in a pocket dimension.

The zombie apocalypse begins again, and Noah decides that he and his family need to abandon the mansion they're living in and head out onto the road in order to avoid being overwhelmed by zombies. The group includes Noah, his wife and two sons, plus Noah's brother, Ian, Ian's wife and daughter, and some others.

In [chapter 35](https://www.webtoons.com/en/sf/rebirth/episode-34/viewer?title_no=1412&episode_no=35), some members of the group visit a gas station, and shortly after that, Noah fights a zombie in a nearby building. This zombie puts up a tougher fight than typical zombies.

In [chapter 75](https://www.webtoons.com/en/sf/rebirth/s2-episode-73/viewer?title_no=1412&episode_no=75), the group is travelling in a truck when they encounter a roadblock manned by armed soldiers, which leads to a confrontation between the two parties.

The story has its own [wiki page](https://webtoon.fandom.com/wiki/Rebirth) with more detailed descriptions of the characters.